# Java - Regex to validate if String is in StatsD format

Tags: java, regex

Essentially, I want to validate if each of the strings is in StatsD Format, which is something like this -

```
<metric_name>:<_value>|<metric_type>|#dim1:valueX,dim2:valueY
```

There can be several dims and values.

Sample Strings :

```
jvm.memory.used:9591960|g|#statistic:value,area:nonheap,id:Compressed Class Space

jvm.memory.free:9591960|g|#statistic:value,area:nonheap


 jvm.memory.free:9591960|g|#
```

For starters, I came up with -

```
\w+:\d+\|g\|#[\w+:\w+,]+
```

Any help?

Try here - https://regex101.com/r/12ZB2u/1/

Comment: `.` isn't matched by `\w`. You could use the negated class `[^:]` instead. Also `[\w+:\w+,]` should be `(\w+:\w+,)*(\w+:\w+)`. Since you're validating full lines, you will also want to add anchors

Comment: (\w+:\w+,)*(\w+:\w+) - is not covering spaces in value after :

Comment: Indeed, `\w` represents 'word-characters' and is the same as `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` (unicode ignored at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it -

```
^[\w.]+:\d+\|g\|#(?:[\w.]+:[^,\n]+(?:,|$))*$
```

Something like this - https://regex101.com/r/12ZB2u/4

Answer (score 0):

```
(\w+\.?)+:\d+\|g\|#[\w+:\w+,]+
```

and including the complete sentence (with whitespaces) :

```
(\w+\.?)+:\d+\|g\|#[\w+:\w+,\ ]+
```